# Which internal WiFi cards are compatible with my MacBook Pro?

Tags: wifi

I have a 2017 15 inch Macbook Pro and just upgraded to fiber internet. I'm guessing a standard M.2 WiFi 6 card would be compatible with it like this one?

https://www.newegg.com/fenvi-ax200ngw-pcie-half-mini-card-m-2/p/0XM-00JK-00064?Description=WiFi%206%20card&cm_re=WiFi_6_card-_-9SIADXZ9H62090-_-Product

Also it seems that some Lenovo laptops have a whitelist in the BIOS preventing people from upgrading their WiFi card in Thinkpads? Not sure on this one though.

Comment: what makes you think you need anew wifi card?  The one you showed is for a PC.

Comment: To upgrade from Wifi 5 to Wifi 6. It's just a nice thing to have